# How can I search for a specific string in an email thread in Microsoft Outlook for Android?

Tags: email, search, outlook

I have opened an email thread (aka conversation) in Microsoft Outlook for Android. I would like to search a string (e.g., word or phrase).

How can I search for a specific word in an email thread in Microsoft Outlook for Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible as of today with Outlook version 4.0.90.

You can always open the mailbox in your web browser and use the Find in Page functionality.